# Internal links not working on appengine deployed site

Tags: google-app-engine

I just deployed a website for testing on Google Appengine.
Using google App Engine Launcher Its successfully done.

Now I tried to open the deployed website, please check here https://acuteservice-1260.appspot.com the internal pages are not opening.

Below is my APP YAML file

```
application: acuteservice-1260
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff))

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: index.php
```

Comment: What do you mean by the internal pages are not opening? Are there any errors being thrown up?

Comment: No error everything is OK, If i am clicking about.php its still showing the home page.

Comment: added a line to serve all php scripts without bothering about the actual names. Have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below YAML, all static files should go to "static" folder.

```
application: acuteservice-1260
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

default_expiration: "30d"

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  mime_type: text/cache-manifest
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  expiration: "0m"

- url: /(.*\.atom)
  mime_type: application/atom+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.atom)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.crx)
  mime_type: application/x-chrome-extension
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.crx)

- url: /(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.css)

- url: /(.*\.eot)
  mime_type: application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.eot)

- url: /(.*\.htc)
  mime_type: text/x-component
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.htc)

- url: /(.*\.php)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.php)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.ico)
  mime_type: image/x-icon
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ico)
  expiration: "7d"

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)

- url: /(.*\.json)
  mime_type: application/json
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.json)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.m4v)
  mime_type: video/m4v
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.m4v)

- url: /(.*\.mp4)
  mime_type: video/mp4
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.mp4)

- url: /(.*\.(ogg|oga))
  mime_type: audio/ogg
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(ogg|oga))

- url: /(.*\.ogv)
  mime_type: video/ogg
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ogv)

- url: /(.*\.otf)
  mime_type: font/opentype
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.otf)

- url: /(.*\.rss)
  mime_type: application/rss+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.rss)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.safariextz)
  mime_type: application/octet-stream
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.safariextz)

- url: /(.*\.(svg|svgz))
  mime_type: images/svg+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(svg|svgz))

- url: /(.*\.swf)
  mime_type: application/x-shockwave-flash
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.swf)

- url: /(.*\.ttf)
  mime_type: font/truetype
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ttf)

- url: /(.*\.txt)
  mime_type: text/plain
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.txt)

- url: /(.*\.unity3d)
  mime_type: application/vnd.unity
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.unity3d)

- url: /(.*\.webm)
  mime_type: video/webm
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.webm)

- url: /(.*\.webp)
  mime_type: image/webp
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.webp)

- url: /(.*\.woff)
  mime_type: application/x-font-woff
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.woff)

- url: /(.*\.xml)
  mime_type: application/xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xml)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.xpi)
  mime_type: application/x-xpinstall
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xpi)

# image files
- url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

# audio files
- url: /(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))  

# windows files
- url: /(.*\.(doc|exe|ppt|rtf|xls))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(doc|exe|ppt|rtf|xls))

# compressed files
- url: /(.*\.(bz2|gz|rar|tar|tgz|zip))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bz2|gz|rar|tar|tgz|zip))

# index files
- url: /(.+)/
  static_files: static/\1/index.php
  upload: static/(.+)/index.php
  expiration: "15m"

- url: /(.+)
  static_files: static/\1/index.php
  upload: static/(.+)/index.php
  expiration: "15m"

# site root
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.php
  upload: static/index.php
  expiration: "15m"

- url: .*
  script: index.php
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because you've instructed app engine to route all actions(`.*`) through `index.php`. You'll realise that when you navigate to any path on your site it get's redirected to `index.php`.

What you can do is to add more url mappings for all the other pages in your site and these should come before the index.php mapping.

```
- url: /about.php
  script: about.php
- url: /services.php
  script: services.php
```

etc.

Then you can put your catch all url mapping to `index.php` last.

If that'll be too much of a hassle and there are a bunch of php files you could use something like this to serve all php scripts:

```
application: acuteservice-1260
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff))

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey is there any other method without adding catch all ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. By catch all I meant your `.*` that you're using. You could specifically map `/` to index.php, and then delete your current mapping `.*`. That way when you navigate to a wrong path it'll throw a 404 instead of showing your index script

Comment: Ok Its not working The url "/index.php" does not match any handlers.

Comment: - url: /services
  script: services.php

Not working

Comment: the url 'index.php' will not match any handlers if you have not set it up do so. For it to match you'll have to write a handler to handle that. Like `-url: /index.php script: index.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107259/discussion-between-jeffrey-godwyll-and-niharika-parida).

Comment: This is not the solution all static files should go to static folder.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer! Working like a charm.